# Indy 10 projects being flagged as malware?

Tags: delphi, indy10, malware, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I recently had to update indy for my 22-year-old application now being written in D5. Well, that was fun but I needed TLS ver 1.2. With the new OpenSSL DLL's everything worked fine with D5 and Indy10.

I am starting to play around with Delphi Seatle as I am getting ready to write a new program. Thought I would start with a simple Indy 10 project since now Indy is preinstalled. As I dropped individual Indy components, I would do a quick compile. Everything was fine until I dropped a TIdHTTP component. When compiled, Avira moved it immediately to its quarantine folder saying that it contained malware. When I removed the TIdHTTP component and the IdHTTP from my uses clause, Avira liked it again.

So, I figured it must be some sort of but and upgraded to Delhi 10.1, Berlin just to find out that Avira still flags anything with the TidHTTP component or IdHttp.pas in the uses clause as malware.

Now, this was just a practice app as next week I am starting a real project, but this really sucks. I submitted my Project1.exe to Avira and they confirmed it was indeed infected with Malware 'TR/ATRAPS.Gen'. This doesn't happen with D5 for a Win32 program. In Seatle and Berlin, I was targeting Win64. Never tried to see what happens if targeted as a Win32 app.

Indy Developers, why is this happening and how do I fix it? I sell my software and as a customer, I wouldn't buy a program with Malware. FYI, I have completed 3 complete 'all files' scans with Avira and the only bad files it found were the ones I compiled with IdHTTP (Indy 10) with Seattle and Berlin.

Comment: Avira is detecting a heuristic caused by the fact that some malware authors have written code that uses Delphi and Indy. You need to work with Avira to better check your application and what it's doing. This has nothing to do with Indy developers or Seattle/Berlin (other than that malware authors have chosen to use them to create their code), and there''s absolutely nothing they can do about it. It doesn't happen with D5 because it clearly generates different code that doesn't trigger the same alarm.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. When I get ready to release a program written with indy and Delphi that is triggering Avira, I will definitely work with them. I don't need anything that scares unknowing customers. Sorry for asking again. I just needed confirmation. Thanks again.